# How to configure swagger UI so it doesn't need the URL?

Tags: go, swagger, go-gin

I am using http://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger to auto-generate the swagger and also create the UI as below.

Everything works fine when I am running the server on my machine but when I run the server on Kubernetes the UI cannot find the doc.json and shows `Failed to load spec.` and in the browser I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED localhost:9080/swagger/doc.json:1`.

As it can be seen the problem is the URL that points to the localhost and it is not accessible from outside of the cluster. If I use `http://my_public_url/reverse_proxy_entry_for_my_service/swagger/doc.json` then everything is working fine and in the UI I can see the generated swagger.

My question is how I can remove this dependency to the public_url? I need to launch my component on multiple URL and if possible I want to make it independent from the URL otherwise I have to use an environment variable to pass and configure the URL.

My code:

```golang
    url := ginSwagger.URL("http://localhost:9080/swagger/doc.json")
    r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler, url))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `url` parameter, so it will be like this:

```
r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler))
```

The handler can locate the `doc.json` itself.

Comment: Doesn't work and I get `502 badgateway` from Nginx in front. This is my get: `r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler))`

Comment: Try to change the URL to `swagger/doc.json` or `/swagger/doc.json`

Comment: No, not working. `/swagger/doc.json` returned 404 and failed to load spec and `swagger/doc.json` bad gateway from Nginx infront.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the steps, and in the end, I got **Internal Server Error**, **HTTP status code 500**.

```
[GIN] 2023/02/07 - 16:35:47 | 500 |      27.569µs |      172.17.0.1 | GET      "/swagger/doc.json"
```

To fix the problem:

1. Make sure you have added the necessary annotations for the endpoints.

```
// @BasePath /api/v1

// PingExample godoc
// @Summary ping example
// @Schemes
// @Description do ping
// @Tags example
// @Accept json
// @Produce json
// @Success 200 {string} ok
// @Router /ping [get]
```

2. You have run the `swag init` command at the root of your project.
3. You have imported the folder where Swagger generated the docs.
   In the file where you have added the Swagger middleware to the Gin engine.

```
_ "company.com/name-of-project/docs"
```

as per the **swaggo** issue raised and resolved here https://github.com/swaggo/swag/issues/830

Happy coding!